# typescript, javascript, angular, nginx, alpine, docker communications in the network via nginx i think i missed something. looking for a review

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, express, nginx

once i migrated to docker to have a virtual network to simulate an atual network (bridge type with dns      which works . the fqdn is resolved correctly to referrring ip) the following errors appeared in the console.log AND no data is displayed on the frontend website.

```
ERROR Error: NG0901

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://backend:4000/crafts. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

 ERROR
 Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://backend:4000/crafts", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://backend:4000/crafts: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
```

thats the browser's (firefox) console.log

i think nginx is doing things with the headers and or the body is empty due to serversides configs with nginx

on local host everything worked out fine

so im on the config of gninx  but so far without any success.. i read about similar problems but couldnt find a solution myself OR the answers read didnt work with my setup.
i tries to change the ip to 0.0.0.0 to make it accessable in the network

oh AND im using nodejs expressjs
app.listen(port,ip)

I use a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml to make the images, i use a powershell script to compose the images

what i suspect to cause the problem is:
backend:

index.js is run anbd looks like that

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const express_1 = __importDefault(require("express"));
const Routes_1 = __importDefault(require("./Routes"));
const app = (0, express_1.default)();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
next();
});
// middleswares
app.use(express_1.default.json());
app.use(express_1.default.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //changed to see wheater it would effect the package isssue- should allow
app.use(Routes_1.default);
app.listen(4000,'0.0.0.0'); // or fqdn 'frontend'
console.log('server on port', 4000);
```

this is generated from index.ts and a build command

the referrring dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app/

COPY .  /app/

COPY package.json /app/
COPY package-lock.json /app/
RUN cd /app/
RUN npm install -g
RUN npm update express
RUN npm install pg

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=builder ./app/dist ./usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 3999-6001

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

RUN apk add --update nodejs
RUN apk add --update npm
```

after the image runs i open the terminal and run in the usr/share/gninx/html directory :

```
 npm i express
 npm i pg
 node index.js
```

then I install vim
and edit the nginx.config like that

```
  vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

i add a server directory, make it listen to the fqdn 'frontend' or its referring IP and the port 4000

```
 listen ip:port  kind of syntax
```

i add error and access logs earlier on and it doesn't return problems besides sometimes it says that IP are not available. im lacking on the understanding on how to interpret that

the PostgreSQL is also running in a docker container by the default port 5432 and the fqdn database which is also properly resolvable

same as the backend's fqdn

there is so much more stuff that links the short pieces of code that i have.. feel free to request more if interested or if u think it'd be required to find out whats going wrong.

Comment: every container is pingable. just saying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt my lesson..
servers listen to their own IPs, or at their localhost.
so i had a misconception there. though thanks to the pple taking a look inside here.

also a nodejs expressjs server doesn't necessarily need nginx to run on.. node is enough.. for the purpose..
fixing these two things led functionality as designed :)

so this can be closed or used as reminder on these two things:

understanding the conceptional idea of how networks work
AND
understanding the tech-stack being used and how it works

else
/closed

Comment: If you believe that the question and your answer will help others with similar problems, you can just leave them up -- if you feel otherwise you can just delete them on your own.